# Qt Which signal is emitted when the DOM changed due to ajax

Tags: c++, ajax, qt, dom, signals-slots

In QWebView, which signal is emitted while the DOM stucture of the page changes? For example ajax form can generate new DOM elements on the existing page without reloading the URL or something else.

Answer (score 0):

No signal is emitted for DOM changes specifically. One way to solve that problem was that when I knew when that event should happen, I started a QTimer immediately after the loadFinished signal was emitted when the page was loaded, and connected it's timeout signal to a function which would emit the loadFinished signal again. The QTimer's timeout value was the time I knew should pass when the change will occur.